# How can I see my VCAP_SERVICES environment variable with the cf program?

Tags: cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

When I run `cf env <app-name>` it shows all the environment variables I've set with `cf set-env`, but I don't see the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.  How can I see that variable's value?

Comment: cf env APP_NAME

Answer (score 10):

As of version 6.10 of the `cf` program, the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment will now be displayed with the other environment variables, with the command `cf env <app-name>`.

To upgrade your `cf` program, download the appropriate version on the releases page: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Answer (score 1):

Use the cf env command to view the Cloud Foundry environment variables for your application. cf env displays the following environment variables:

```
The VCAP_SERVICES variables existing in the container environment
The user-provided variables set using the cf set-env command
```

For details please refer:

http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

Answer (score 1):

**cf env app-name** gives VCAP_SERVICES values.

Answer (score 1):

***Here is the small snippet to list all the environment variables of PCF:***

```
cf ssh <App_Name> -c "python -c 'import os, json; print(json.dumps({key:value for (key,value) in os.environ.items()}, indent = 2))'"

{
"INSTANCE_GUID": "315c18fb-e031-4e6e-67c4-84d1",
"CF_INSTANCE_PORT": "61064",
"CF_INSTANCE_KEY": "/etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.key",
"USER": "vcap",
"INSTANCE_INDEX": "0",
.
.
.
.
"PWD": "/home/vcap",
"VCAP_APP_PORT": "8080"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**cf env your-app-name** gives VCAP_SERVICES values, but only when your application was bonded with service, else you will have only VCAP_APPLICATION variable.