# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory error while starting application in Bluemix

Tags: java, hibernate, ibm-cloud

Once I deploy my Java Application to IBM Bluemix, it can't create the initial database connection due to this error:

> Building new Hibernate SessionFactory 2015-04-11 14:24:04 [main] ERROR
>   o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure The last packet
>   sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has
>   not received any packets from the server.)

I tried to set the "hibernate.current_session_context_class" to "thread" (which solved the problem when I deployed the same app to Google Application Engine) but that didn't help with Websphere Liberty Profile:

```
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" >
        thread
 </prop>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1 ---** This is the actual root cause. Bluemix offers the ClearDB MySQL service but its pipeline cannot connect to it :(

> Building new Hibernate SessionFactory 2015-04-11 15:04:49 [main] ERROR
>   o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

**UPDATE 2 ---** Even the Experimental MySQL DB is also off limits if there's any attempt to connect from the pipeline machines:

> o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
>     at org.hibe     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)    at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
>     ... 40 more Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "its pipeline cannot connect to it".  Are you talking about the DevOps build/test/deploy pipelines?  Was there a particular part of a pipeline where you saw this problem?

Comment: The very first step of the pipeline (Build Stage) runs the unit tests, which try to connect to a MySQL database hosted outside Bluemix (i.e., ClearDB). If I try to deploy directly by using "cf push" the application does not even start because of the presence of "spring-core.jar" and that triggers the error: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated
.. Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer. Too many issues..

Comment: And I do have "spring-context" declared in my pom.xml. Looks like the "Starter Code" app plays nice with the pipeline because the war is produced through "ant" and it sets the Archive folder as "output", I am not quite sure but the Maven build and Deploy are not configurable in a very intuitive way, I am now using the "-DskipTests" flag just to see if I can deploy through the pipeline,  but no luck so far.. the "Deploy Stage" continues to miss the artifact (i.e., my .war), looks like they are not retrieved from the "build-slave" machine and copied into the "deploy-slave" machine. Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ok.  So this is happening because the Liberty buildpack autowires in JDBC connections for you during deployment to Bluemix.  For the unit tests you will need to provide this connection info to your app.

Comment: The problem is that, for this exercise (academic research), I must use a MySQL database and, as we know, in Bluemix atm we have Experimental MySQL and ClearDB MySQL (hosted outside Bluemix's infrastructure), when I posted this question I was trying to run unit tests through the pipeline to connect with the ClearDB, so I guess the pipeline machines are closed to any external communication, which blocked me in this case. So I decided to use IBM's MySQL, created a PHP app purely to use PHPMyAdmin to set up my DB. At the moment I really wanted to make the "Deploy Stage" recognize my .war artifact.

Comment: ClearDB is hosted on the public Internet.  You can actually access it from your local machine.  Log into Bluemix and click on your app.  You will see a box for ClearDB.  There will be a button that says "Show Credentials".  Click that and you can get your connection info.  Also check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550468/how-can-i-see-my-vcap-services-environment-variable-with-the-cf-program on how to do it command line.